# OLEUnInitialize() in windows 7

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new at MFC. I am Using OLEINitialize() to initialize a COM object, COCreateInstance() to create an instance of the object(EXCEL.EXE), & OLEUnInitialize() to uninitialize the com object. But in windows XP, after the call of OLEUnInitialize(), the EXCEL.EXE ends. But In windows 7 it doesn't. If you guys have any idea please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Constructor:

```
CXLAutomation::CXLAutomation(BOOL bVisible)
{
    m_pdispExcelApp = NULL;
    m_pdispWorkbook = NULL;
    m_pdispWorksheet = NULL;
    m_pdispActiveChart = NULL;
    InitOLE();       
    StartExcel();
    SetExcelVisible(bVisible);
    CreateWorkSheet();

}
```

Destructor:

```
CXLAutomation::~CXLAutomation()
{
    ReleaseDispatch();
    OleUninitialize();
}
```

Functions:

```
BOOL CXLAutomation::InitOLE()
{
    DWORD dwOleVer;

    dwOleVer = CoBuildVersion();

    // check the OLE library version
    if (rmm != HIWORD(dwOleVer)) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Incorrect version of OLE libraries.", L"Failed", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // could also check for minor version, but this application is
    // not sensitive to the minor version of OLE

    // initialize OLE, fail application if we can't get OLE to init.
    if (FAILED(OleInitialize(NULL))) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot initialize OLE.", L"Failed", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return FALSE;
    }


    return TRUE;

}

BOOL CXLAutomation::StartExcel()
{
    CLSID clsExcelApp;

    // if Excel is already running, return with current instance
    if (m_pdispExcelApp != NULL)
        return TRUE;

    /* Obtain the CLSID that identifies EXCEL.APPLICATION
     * This value is universally unique to Excel versions 5 and up, and
     * is used by OLE to identify which server to start.  We are obtaining
     * the CLSID from the ProgID.
     */
    if (FAILED(CLSIDFromProgID(L"Excel.Application", &clsExcelApp))) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot obtain CLSID from ProgID", L"Failed", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // start a new copy of Excel, grab the IDispatch interface
    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(clsExcelApp, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void**)&m_pdispExcelApp))) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot start an instance of Excel for Automation.", L"Failed", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OleInitialize` and `OleUninitialize` are not for COM objects.  They are for initializing and uninitializing the *COM library* on a given thread.  You should not call `OleUninitialize` until you are done using COM, i.e. you have no more COM objects.

Comment: I called OLEUnInitialize() in the destructor of my xl automation class. but even if the object goes out of scope, the EXCEL.EXE doesn't ends. And is there any way to stop it, because it is causing a memory leak in my program.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call Release() on the COM object you've created in order to free it.

Comment: I did. but still does not ends the process. but it does work in Windows XP. I suppose there is problem with OleUnInitialize().

Comment: I think it's more likely a problem with your code than with OleUnInitialize.  Perhaps you'd like to share some of it with us?  Remove code that isn't relevant tothe problem until you've reduced it to the smallest possible segment that exhibits the problem.  In so doing you might even find the fault yourself.

Comment: In the code above you're not calling Release on the m_pdispExcelApp pointer.  Like this... m_pdispExcelApp->Release();

Comment: ReleaseDispatch() function calls it.